# Nsis installer to delete files either through a post section or on the close button in a custom dialog

Tags: nsis, delete-file

I have an installer that goes to a specified network location to install some add-ins before it installs the main program.  I need to figure a way to have nsis delete those files after the close button is clicked.

I tried to setup a post section and could not get it to delete the files. Any suggestions on how to either capture  onclick for the close button on the last custom page or some other way I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Function Cleanup
Delete ...
FunctionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
Call Cleanup
FunctionEnd

Function .onInstFailed
Call Cleanup
FunctionEnd
```

Having a final section should work as well. You should try to figure out why it is unable to delete the files. My guess is that the path is wrong or the files are locked by some other application. [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) should be able to help you figure out why the delete fails...

Comment: It didnt even try to run the code.  I have some buttons on the last page that allow the apps to run again if they found any issues during the install. will .onInstSuccess wait untill the last custom page is done or does it run after the "install" section completes?

Comment: That worked great.  after the final custom page is run and you click close it then deletes the files just like I needed. Thanks so much Anders.